convolution of sequences in $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$
Let $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z}) = \{ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} : x_n \in \mathbb{C} \text{ and } \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^{N} |x_n|^p < \infty \}$ for $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be any two elements of $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$.
(a) Prove that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{m=-N}^{N} x_{n - m} y_m$ exists for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
(b) If $z_n = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{m=-N}^{N} x_{n - m} y_m$, then prove that $\{z_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$.
(c) Conclude that $\{z_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \in \ell^{P}(\mathbb{Z})$ for all $p \in (1, \infty)$.
For part (a) since it is N-th term of cauchy product(which is convergent) so its convergent to zero
(b) is true by holder inequality.
How to proceed for part (c) it is obvious from first 2 parts.

The assumptions can be relaxed. Namely if $(x_n)\in \ell^1$ and $(y_n)\in \ell^p$  then (a), (b) and (c) are satisfied.

how can one proove it , using holder inequality

$\{z_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ implies that $|z_n| \to 0$ as $|n| \to \infty$. In particular, there exists $N$ such that  $|z_n|<1$ for $|n| \ge N$. Note that (since $p>1$) $|z_n| <1$ implies $|z_n|^{p} <|z_n|$. Can you finish?

okay done , i fould where i missed

check my arguments
